# Why do typescript adds empty string to the union of conditional returns?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
type Item = {
    prop: string;
}

type Items = {
    [key: string]: Item
}

type App = {
    selectedItem?: string;
}

type State = {
    items: Items;
    app: App;
}

const selector = ({ items, app }: State) =>
    app.selectedItem && items[app.selectedItem]
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=48#)

The return type of `selector` is: `"" | Item | undefined`.

I can't see any possibility how can the above function could return an empty string.

- If the first item in the conditional is `undefined`, then it returns `undefined`.
- If the first one has a truthy value, but the second one doesn't have the property with the first item as a key, it also returns `undefined`.
- If both of them are truthy, it returns the requested property from the object, which is `Item`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `app.selectedItem` is a falsy value, then that value will be returned.

So if it is an empty string, this will return an empty string. You can test this easily by entering this in your JS console. It will evaluate to `""`.

```
"" && true
```